# firebase dynamic links plugin not working with campaigns

Tags: ionic3, firebase-dynamic-links

I installed the firebase-dynamic-links plugin in my Ionic3 app for tracking some events in Firebase, for example, when a user installed the app or the user open the first time. But these actions were not register in Firebase console.

I followed the steps described in the documentation, I configured Firebase:

- I added a project, I put the application data (Android and IO version): bundleId, appStoreId, AppId, TeamId
- I added a dynamik-link.
- I saved the files google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist
  Then, I configured my application.

I installed and configured the plugin firebase-dynamic-links:

- I installed the plugin: ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks --save --variable APP_DOMAIN = "https://mydomain/" --variable APP_PATH = "/" --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID = REVERSE_ID --variable PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION = "ONE DESCRIPTION"
- I added the google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist files to the project folder. Too these files was copied into folders platforms/ ios/ and platforms/android/
- Added FirebaseDynamicLinks module into app.module.ts and I added the promisse this.firebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink () in my app.component.ts file to redirect to home page. And did not put more in the application.

I Built and I uploaded my app into the App Store

And after, I tested without good results: I downloaded the application directly, I downloaded the application using the dynamic link with the campaign attributes and only counted the direct installations by
AppStore, not from the campaign links.

So, does this plugin record these events for the campaign? what I have to configure?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your dynamic link?

Comment: The link is something like: https://SHORT_GOOGLE_URL/?link=http://my_app.com/home&apn=PACKAGE_NAME&isi=A_BIG_NUMBER&ibi=PACKAGE_NAME&utm_campaign=name-test3&utm_medium=medium-test3&utm_source=quelle-test3

Comment: Please try appending &d=1 to the end of the link and navigate to this page. If there are any errors/warnings, that may be an issue. 
To diagnose the issue we need the actual link (without obfuscation), feel free to open Firebase Support ticket and include that info.

Comment: Thanks @OleksiyIvanov for you response.  
I spoke with my boss and currently I can not give you the URL without obfuscation, I am sorry. But, I appended your param in a browser and shows a diagram with 3 flows : one for Android, iOS and Desktop. Any error/warning is no printed. 
What can I do more?
Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ensuring your App(s) actually receiving the dynamic link. Try to add logging to your App code and observe that link is being passed to the App. Another option is to show alert view when you received the link.

If you can share source code of small test App, that reproduces the issue, I will try to look at it. No promises, as Ionic is not an officially supported Firebase platform.

Comment: Hello Oleksiy, thanks for you response.  
 I did a new app for test  and I did a dynamic link 
 https://w5639.app.goo.gl/xJdE 
The code:    
`code this.firebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink() . 
   .then((res: any) => {
    localStorage.setItem('onDynamicLink_res', JSON.stringify(res));  
   })   
   .catch((error: any) => { . 
    localStorage.setItem('onDynamicLink_error', error);  
   });`   
The variable res is a object with attributes: invitationId, deepLink and clickTimestamp. The attribute deepLink has the params utm_medium, utm_source..

Comment: @Jose did you ever get the campaign params to show up?